# no effect of PLD in cortex A9

Tags: arm, neon, cortex-a

I am using the following program to check the effect of `PLD` on performance. However, I couldn't find the difference in performance with and without `PLD` the C code I've written. Is there anything I am missing or any compiler option I need to add?

```
int arra[6144] = {0};      /*15kb*/
int arrb[6144] = {0};       /*15kb*/
int arrc[6144] = {0};       /*15kb*/
int arrd[2048] = {0};      /*5kb*/
int arre[2048] = {0};       /*5kb*/
int arrf[2048] = {0};       /*5kb*/
int arrg[2048] = {0};      /*5kb*/
int arrh[2048] = {0};       /*5kb*/
int arri[2048] = {0};       /*5kb*/
int arrj[2048] = {0};      /*5kb*/
int arrk[2048] = {0};       /*5kb*/
int arrl[2048] = {0};       /*5kb*/




int main()
{
    int csize;
    int i,z = 3;
    int loop_i;
    int32x4_t viarrd,viarre,viarrf;
    int32x4_t viarrg,viarrh,viarri;
    int32x4_t viarrj,viarrk,viarrl;

    asm("LDR r1, =arrd");
    asm("LDR r2, =arre");
    asm("LDR r3, =arrf");
    asm("LDR r4, =arrg");
    asm("LDR r5, =arrh");

          asm ("PLD [r1]");
    asm ("PLD [r2]");
    asm ("PLD [r3]");
    asm ("PLD [r4]");
    asm ("PLD [r5]");

for(loop_i=0;loop_i<100;loop_i++)
{
    for(i=0;i<2048;i++)
    {

        arrd[i] = 5;
        arre[i] = 5;
        arrf[i] = 5;
        arrg[i] = 5;
        arrh[i] = 5;
        arri[i] = 5;
        arrj[i] = 5;
        arrk[i] = 5;
        arrl[i] = 5;
    }

    for(i=0;i<2048;i+=4)
    {
        viarrf = vld1q_s32(&arrf[i]);
        viarre = vld1q_s32(&arre[i]);
        viarrd = vmulq_s32(viarrf,viarre);
        vst1q_s32(&arrd[i],viarrd);
    }
    for(i=0;i<2048;i+=4)
    {
        viarrg = vld1q_s32(&arrg[i]);
        viarrh = vld1q_s32(&arrh[i]);
        viarri = vmulq_s32(viarrg,viarrh);
        vst1q_s32(&arri[i],viarri);
    }
    for(i=0;i<2048;i+=4)
    {
        viarrj = vld1q_s32(&arrj[i]);
        viarrk = vld1q_s32(&arrk[i]);
        viarrl = vmulq_s32(viarrj,viarrk);
        vst1q_s32(&arrl[i],viarrl);
    }
    for(i=0;i<2048;i+=4)
    {
        viarrd = vld1q_s32(&arrd[i]);
        viarrf = vld1q_s32(&arrf[i]);
        viarre = vmulq_s32(viarrd,viarrf);
        vst1q_s32(&arre[i],viarre);
    }
    for(i=0;i<2048;i+=4)
    {
        viarrg = vld1q_s32(&arrg[i]);
        viarri = vld1q_s32(&arri[i]);
        viarrh = vmulq_s32(viarrg,viarri);
        vst1q_s32(&arrh[i],viarrh);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your description says Cortex-A9 but the tag says Cortex-A8 - which is it? On Cortex-A8 pld only loads to L2 and your data set already fits in L2, so if it's already there it won't benefit from preloading.

That said, your code wouldn't accomplish an awful lot regardless of whether or not it's on Cortex-A8 or A9 because a single pld will only load a single cache line (32-64 bytes); it won't tell the CPU to keep prefetching lines after that forever. An effective usage of the pld instruction, is to issue it inside your loop iteration such that it's pointing multiple cache lines ahead of where you're currently loading from. Ideally you'd structure your loop such that one cache line's worth of loads are done per pld, in order to avoid redundant ones. Also, you'd align your data sets to cache line width.

However, Cortex-A9 has an automatic prefetcher that will detect strides. If you are on Cortex-A9 and this feature is turned on the pld might not be helping much or at all, and will instead just waste time going through the pipeline.